Overflow wrap does not adjust text width
I want the text div to be centered but the text to be aligned left.
The inner div (#introduction-child) is wider than its content. Instead it should be the width of the text (max-width 80vw).
The font-size seems to be changing the font size without changing its containers width.
Any idea how I can make it fit to content?
EDIT: I want the width of the child container to adjust [if the text is too wide for the container (>80vw)] to the width of the text after a linebreak happened. Please see photos below what it is supposed to look like/what it should not look like.


#introduction {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#introduction-child {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 80vw;
  background-color: #80b0ff;
  margin-top: 28vh;
}

#introduction h2 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  /* ??*/
}
<div id="introduction">
  <div id="introduction-child">
    <h2>Max Mustermann</h2>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ad</h2>
    <h2>Lorem amet, consectetur ad</h2>
  </div>
</div>



This is what it is supposed to be like
The Blue box should shrink to the text width. The red part should not exist

Instead of using max-width, try to use width: fit-content; for #introduction-child.

What’s it supposed to look like when the viewport is too small for everything to be seen at once? ie which elements scroll?

Isn't it actually doing the right thing at the moment?

@mrconcerned It is not. If you shrink the browser windows it leaves some space to the right side of the text. I uploaded a second photo. I hope that makes it clear

give the min height and width to max to outer wrapper and then gave width as fit-content to the children with max height and width
this is my version of the answer and hope this works :)


#introduction {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          background-color: grey;
          min-height: 100vh;
          min-width: 100vw;
        }

        #introduction-child {
          overflow-wrap: break-word;
          width: fit-content;
          max-width: 80%;
          max-height: 80%;
          background-color: #80b0ff;
          margin-top: 20vh;
        }

        #introduction h2 {
          font-size: 1.8em;
        }
      
<div id="introduction">
  <div id="introduction-child">
    <h2>Max Mustermann</h2>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ad</h2>
    <h2>Lorem amet, consectetur ad</h2>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks for the code. Unfortunately it still leaves some space to the right side when a line-break happens (shrinking the browser windows)

to solve this problem please use align-item:center instead of justify-content: center;


#introduction {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; /* This vertically centers the content */
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#introduction-child {
  display: inline-block; /* Allows the width to fit the content */
  max-width: 80vw; /* Constrains the maximum width */
  background-color: #80b0ff;
  text-align: left; /* Ensures text is left-aligned */
  margin-top: 28vh;
}

#introduction h2 {
  font-size: 1.8em; /* Font size scaling */
  margin: 0; /* Removes default margin if needed */
}
<div id="introduction">
  <div id="introduction-child">
    <h2>Max Mustermann</h2>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ad</h2>
    <h2>Lorem amet, consectetur ad</h2>
  </div>
</div>




Not quite what OP asked.

Thanks for the code but it still leaves some space to the right if a line-break occurs

remove the overflow-wrap: break-word; i have updated the code snippet


I want the text div to be centered but the text to be aligned left.

This is exactly what happens in your snippet. No problem.

The inner div (#introduction-child) is wider than its content. Instead
it should be the width of the text (max-width 80vw).

No, your snippet shows that the the inner div is the same width as the text. No problem.

The font-size seems to be changing the font size without changing its
containers width.

I do not understand what you mean, and the font-size does not appear to change.
